# When is $\text{lcm}(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\text{lcm}(n, m)} - 1$ true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We know the following:

For all $a, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1.$$

But when is the following true?

$$\text{lcm}(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\text{lcm}(n, m)} - 1.$$

*i.e.* can we give some conditions on $a,m$ and $n$ such that the above result holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $a\geq 2,$ it’s true if and only if  $m\mid n$ or $n\mid m.$

We will assume $d=\gcd(m,n)=1.$ If not, let $a_1=a^d, m_1=m/d,n_1=n/d,$ and we get the case when $\gcd(m_1,n_1)=1.$

Note that:

$$\operatorname{lcm}(A,B)=\frac{AB}{\gcd(A,B)}$$

Assume $n<m.$ Then:

$$\begin{align}L&=\operatorname{lcm}(a^m-1,a^n-1)\\&=\frac{(a^n-1)(a^m-1)}{a^{d}-1}\\
&=\left(1+a+a^{2} + \cdots +a^{n-1}\right)(a^m-1)\\
&= a^{m+n-1}+a^{m+n-2}+\cdots +a^{m}- a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}-\cdots -1
\end{align}$$

If $n>1,$ then this is much smaller than $a^{mn}-1.$ In particular:

$$\begin{align}L&< a^{m+n-1}\left(1+a^{-1}+\cdots a^{-(n-1)}\right)-1\\
&\leq a^{m+n-1}\frac1{1-a^{-1}}-1\\
&=\frac{a^{m+n}}{a-1}-1\\
&\leq a^{m+n}-1
\end{align}$$

And when $2\leq n<m,$ we have $n+m<nm.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a solution exists
Let $gcd(n,m)=g$
Let $n=pg$ and $m=qg$     $($note that $gcd(p,q)=1)$
Therefore $lcm(n,m)=pqg$
Product of two numbers = Product of their lcm and gcd.
$$(a^m-1)(a^n-1)=(a^{gcd(n,m)}-1)(a^{lcm(n,m)}-1)$$
$$(a^{qg}-1)(a^{pg}-1)=(a^g-1)(a^{pqg}-1)$$
$$a^{pg}+a^{qg}+a^{g(1+pq)}=a^g+a^{pqg}+a^{g(q+p)}$$
$a^{g+1}$ divides LHS but not RHS unless $p$ or $q=1$
If $p$ or $q=1$ the equation is satisfied
so $gcd(n,m)=n$ or  $m$
The necessary condition is $n=mk$ or $m=kn$ where $k$ is an integer

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around though, that everything that divides the LHS, also divides RHS?

Comment: We can see that $\lcm(a^n-1,a^m-1)|(a^{\lcm(m,n)}-1)$.

Comment: @Mike It is a proof by contradiction. I have edited my answer.

Comment: If $m\mid n$ or $n\mid m$ the statement is true, however, so your conclusion is wrong there.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you elaborate

Comment: ($a^{g+1}$ does not divide the left hand side if $p=1$ or $q=1.$) and if $m\mid n$ or $n\mid m$ the one of $p,q$ is $1.$

Comment: But otherwise, your proof is much more direct than mine.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true for any postive  integer $a \ge 2$ unless $m|n$.

Assume WLOG $m\le n$. Now let $L(a)=(a^m-1)(a^n-1)$. Then  $L$ is a polynomial in $a$ satisfying $L(a) \le a^{2n-1}-1$ if $m$ does not divide $n$. Furthermore LCM$(a^n-1,a^m-1)$ divides $L$.

But setting $M \doteq$ LCM$(m,n)$, it follows that $M \ge 2n$ unless $m$ divides $n$, and so for $a\ge2$: $$a^M-1 \ge a^{2n}-1$$  $$> a^{2n-1}-1 \ge L(a),$$ so $a^M-1$ cannot divide $L(a)$, and so $a^M-1$ cannot be LCM$(a^n-1,a^m-1)$ [because if it were it would divide $L(a)$].